# Generic method with sqlite-net

Tags: c#, sqlite, generics

I want to make a simple repository and underneath there is the method I have used:

```
public static List<T> GetAll()
{
    return _dbConnection.Table<T>().ToList();
}
```

But I am encountering an error:
`'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Table<T>()'`

I use `SQLite` wrapper `sqlite-net`.

Ofc my class is generic:

```
class FeedRepository<T> : IFeedRepository<T>, IDisposable where T : IFeed
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. `T` must have a public parameterless constructor. The following could help you hopefully

```
where T : new()
```

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you just need to add another constraint to `T` - the `Table<T>()` method appears to want the [`new()` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d5x73970.aspx), so you'll need to add that to *your* constraint list too:

```
class FeedRepository<T> : IFeedRepository<T>, IDisposable where T : IFeed, new()
```

At that point, the compiler will know that the `T` type parameter for your class satisfies the constraint for the `T` type parameter of the `Table` method, and it should be fine. Of course, this means that anyone using your `FeedRepository<T>` class can only do so with non-abstract types with a public constructor... but then that's a natural limitation of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the `Table<T>` method has a type constraint of `new()`. However, the generic type parameter of `FeedRepository<T>` does not have such a constraint so you cannot use it directly in `Table<T>`.

You'll need to add a contraint to the `FeedRepository<T>`:

```
class FeedRepository<T> : IFeedRepository<T>, IDisposable where T : IFeed, new()
```